# Traversing all CXXMemberCallExpr in a NamespaceDecl

Tags: c++, clang, abstract-syntax-tree, static-analysis

The idea is to traverse all instances of `CXXMemberCallExpr` inside of a `NamespaceDecl`.

I have a `RecursiveASTVisitor` which is called from an `ASTConsumer`.

The `RecursiveASTVisitor` has an overloaded instance of `VisitNamespaceDecl` in which I call `TraverseDecl` on every declaration I get using another `RecursiveASTVisitor` that has an overloaded instance of `VisitCXXMethodDecl`.

Calling `clang -Xclang -ast-dump myclass.cc` shows the correct hierarchy, so I know it is accessible. Unfortunately, I think that `TraverseDecl` does not go through `CompoundStmt` or `CallExpr`:

```
`-NamespaceDecl 0x555ce9e8b508 prev 0x555ce9e88d38 </class.cc:3:1, line:277:1> line:3:11 my_namespace
    |-original Namespace 0x555ce9e7c268 'my_namespace'
    |-CXXMethodDecl 0x555ce9e8b970 parent 0x555ce9e88da0 prev 0x555ce9e89480 <line:4:1, line:18:1> line:4:16 Init 'void (std::MyOtherClass *, std::my_namespace::paramstruct_t *, const std::object *, std::double, std::int, std::string, std::string, std::ob
f_namespace::MyClass *)'
    | |-ParmVarDecl 0x555ce9e8b5a0 <col:21, col:29> col:29 used env 'std::MyOtherClass *'
    | |-ParmVarDecl 0x555ce9e8b610 <col:34, col:49> col:49 used params 'std::my_namespace::paramstruct_t *'
    | |-ParmVarDecl 0x555ce9e8b680 <line:5:21, col:36> col:36 used j_dd 'const std::object *'
    | |-ParmVarDecl 0x555ce9e8b6f0 <col:47, col:55> col:55 used j_cc 'std::double':'double'
    | |-ParmVarDecl 0x555ce9e8b760 <col:65, col:70> col:70 used j_bb 'std::int':'int'
    | |-ParmVarDecl 0x555ce9e8b7d0 <line:6:21, col:29> col:29 used js_aa 'std::string':'std::_string *'
    | |-ParmVarDecl 0x555ce9e8b840 <col:46, col:54> col:54 used js_ee 'std::string':'std::_string *'
    | |-ParmVarDecl 0x555ce9e8b8b0 <line:7:21, col:32> col:32 used my_class 'std::my_namespace::MyClass *'
    | `-CompoundStmt 0x555ce9e8c3b8 <col:44, line:18:1>
    |   `-CXXMemberCallExpr 0x555ce9e8c350 <line:17:5, col:36> 'void'
    |     |-MemberExpr 0x555ce9e8c2c8 <col:5, col:17> '<bound member function type>' ->Init 0x555ce9e854b0
    |     | `-ImplicitCastExpr 0x555ce9e8c2b0 <col:5> 'std::my_namespace::MyClass *' <LValueToRValue>
    |     |   `-DeclRefExpr 0x555ce9e8c288 <col:5> 'std::my_namespace::MyClass *' lvalue ParmVar 0x555ce9e8b8b0 'my_class' 'std::my_namespace::MyClass *'
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: How about implementing TraverseStmt() to go through the CompoundStmt ?

Comment: Are you interested in an approach that does not use RecursiveASTVisitor?

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to solve this problem is to use AST Matchers. They let you form complex predicates relating AST nodes, like "CXXMemberCallExpr in a particular namespace". This avoids recursive `RecursiveASTVisitors`; the `MatchFinder` will handle all that for you.

In this approach, you would define two elements: a matcher, and a callback that acts when a match is found. The matcher might look like this:

```
// makes a matcher for C++ member call expressions in namespace <ns_name>
auto mk_call_expr_matcher(std::string const & ns_name)
{
  return namespaceDecl(hasName(ns_name),
                       forEachDescendant(cxxMemberCallExpr().bind("call")));
}
```

Note the call to `bind()`; that gives access to the CXXMemberCallExpr AST node in the callback. Also, note the `forEachDescendant` matcher: this is what finds every call expression in the namespace.

To create a callback that prints out a message like "Method 'foo' invoked by object of type 'bar'" for every match, one might do the following:

```
struct CallPrinter : public MatchFinder::MatchCallback {
  void run(MatchFinder::MatchResult const & result) override
  {
    using namespace clang;
    SourceManager & sm(result.Context->getSourceManager());
    CXXMemberCallExpr const * call =
        result.Nodes.getNodeAs<CXXMemberCallExpr>(ns_name_);
    if(call) {
      auto const method_name(call->getMethodDecl()->getNameAsString());
      auto const callee_name(call->getRecordDecl()->getNameAsString());
      std::cout << "Method '" << method_name << "' invoked by object of type '"
                << callee_name << "\n";
    }
    else{ // error reporting... }
    return;
  }

  std::string ns_name_;
}; // struct CallPrinter
```

The argument to the callback, `result`, links to the CXXMemberDecl object (note the `ns_name_`). From there we have all the information relating to the call at our disposal.

I added a complete working example in the file apps/ListCXXMemberCalls.cc in this Code Analysis and Refactoring with Clang Tools demo project. (https://github.com/lanl/coarct) It includes all the boilerplate of instantiating a MatchFinder, registering the matcher and callback, and running it through a Clang tool.